# ошибка конфига на первых этапах настройки

Tags: python, django

в файла urls.py, пытаюсь подключить страничку (приложение) с именем 'page':

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('page/', include('page.urls'))
]
```

сервер возвращает:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'urls' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls__init__.py)**

похоже что как-то неправильно прописываю этот импорт

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, проблема с импортом. Попробуйте так:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('page/', include('page.urls'))
]
```

Comment: ту же ошибку возвращает: "cannot import name 'urls' from 'django.conf.urls"

Comment: @Jimmy ну вы уберите строку `from django.conf.urls import path, include`. Оно здесь не нужно наверное. Посмотрите как в документации этот импорт прописан https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path